# Creating dBase-file sporadically throws exception

Tags: c#, oledb, shapefile, dbase

I'm having trouble creating dbf-files while exporting shapefile data. Most of the times it works, but sometimes it'll just trow the following error, even though the file doesn't exist yet:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'C:\Test\258ba2f1-cc05-4a21-a047-ef060c46a3ca\data\tablename.DBF'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

The code looks something like this:

```
using (var dBaseConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + databasePath + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;"))
        {
            var createTableString = "Create Table " + tableName + ".dbf (p_id char(10), answered char(20), mnote char(50), descr char(50), grade char(50))";

            var cmd = new OleDbCommand(createTableString, dBaseConnection);

            dBaseConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This only happens when i use Microsoft Jet database engine. Using Visual FoxPro creates an additional column named "_NullFlags" and the dbf-file doesn't work with any GIS-software.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you may want to do is to have a "template" table structure always available and never used in production.  Then, just copy that template table to whatever your new table name would need to be.  Then, you can query and connect and do whatever with that file version.  In addition, you can rename the file extension from .DBF to anything, such as YourTable.GISDBF so no other application would even accidentally open it.

However, if that doesn't work for you, you may want to look at [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172330/unspecified-error-when-truncating-large-dbf/10172994#10172994) I answered quite a while back was issues with Jet engine too.  In this case, I am using VFP OleDb driver and using ExecScript().  You can write command line statements and then execute them as if it were a program.  As far as creating the table, you could always do something like creating a CURSOR, and then copying out to the destination table as "TYPE FOXPLUS" which would put it into an older supported file format which might also be readable by GIS.

```
string VFPScript  = "ExecScript( "
      + "[create cursor C_Tmp ( fld1 i, fld2 c(50), fld3 c(10) )] +chr(13)+chr(10)+ "
      + "[copy to '" + YourFileNameVariable + "' type FoxPlus] ";

// put this script into command object, then execute it...
using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand( VFPScript, connection))
{
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```